# Format CSS with VIM like in Textmate

Tags: css, vim, format, textmate, tidy

In TextMate there is this awesome option to "Format CSS" and "Format CSS Compressed". This option doesn't seem to exist in vim. Perhaps it's in a plugin I'm not aware of? Or maybe I need to integrate CSS Tidy somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can integrate CSS Tidy fairly easily. Since you're coming from TextMate I'll assume you're on a Mac. If you don't already have CSS tidy installed, I'd recommend installing it via a package manager, like the excellent [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Once it's installed, you can allow Vim to use CSS tidy for the `=` command, which automatically formats code, by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd filetype css setlocal equalprg=csstidy\ -\ --silent=true
```

Now whenever you have a CSS file open, it will consult CSS Tidy to format it when you invoke the `=` command. Try it on an open CSS file with `gg=G` to format the whole document.

Consult the CSS Tidy [usage guide](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/usage.php) to add any other options you like, and don't forget to escape spaces you add to the above `~/.vimrc` command with `\`.

Comment: Awesome. I noticed csstidy doesn't seem to cuddle opening curly brace in High readability template, but then it doesn't indent properties in Default template. So I corrected the default template a bit to indent properties, available at https://gist.github.com/198ee62a82f74c5e6bf2

Comment: Also noticing dos line feeds appearing from filtering through csstidy. So my autocmd is now `autocmd filetype css setlocal equalprg=csstidy\ -\ --silent=true\ --template=mydefault.tpl\ \|\ dos2unix`

Comment: The problem with `equalprg=csstidy` is that it returns an empty result, if you call it with just the inner contents of a selector (since it is not valid CSS by itself).
I would like to have a function, which calls csstidy and falls back to the internal indenting (equalprg=), if the result is empty.